# Regex excluding characers not working

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, regex-negation

I have a simple regex to return all matches to files from a text file:

```
\\Root_Dir.*?'
```

They start with "`\Root_dir`" and end with a single quote. It works fine, but the problem is I want to exclude files with extension `.rep`. Based on what I read, I tried:

```
\\Root_Dir.*?(?!\.rep)'
```

This still includes files like `\Root_dir\nextdir\happy.rep`.

I would also like to exclude the ending single quote in what is returned if possible

I am using PowerShell 2.0, which I believe supports lookaronds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **negative lookbehind**..i.e you need to lookbehind of single quote for any occurance of `.rep`

```
\\Root_dir[^']*(?<!\.rep)(?=')
```

Comment: That returns a mess because there are multiple.  If I change it to \\Root_dir.*?(?<!\.rep)'  it still includes .rep files.

Comment: @user1921849 check out the edit..i used `[^']` not `.*`..you said that the file always ends with `'`

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Is there a way to not get the single quote at the end returned in the match?

Comment: @user1921849 use `(?=')` instead of `'`

Answer (score 0):

```
\\Root_Dir.*?(?!\.rep)'
```

Consider what the later part of this (after the `.*?`) is asking for, *at the same position in the string*:

- Match single quote
- So not match `\.rep`

clearly this will be true in the example because the `.*?` with match `.rep` and thus the negative look ahead is satisfied.

As .NET supports variable width look-arounds<sup>1</sup>, you need to perform the variable width part within the look ahead before separately performing it for the quote:

```
\\Root_Dir(?!.*?\.rep).*?'
```

However I would be tempted to break this up into:

1. Starts with the prefix: `$value.StartsWith("\\Root_Dir")`
2. If #1 is true then use a regex with a negative loook behind: `(?<!\.rep)'$` (ie. a quote not preceeded by …).

---

<sup>1</sup> No-one told the PM/dev others had concluded it was too hard.

Comment: \\Root_Dir(?!.*?\.rep).*?' returned nothing

Comment: @user1921849 the other (accepted) answer has a better approach than that single regex (without more input data hard to test). I would likely stick with the two part approach because I consider it clearer: complex regexes are often a maintenance issue.